# Infinite families of Moore graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Is there another infinite family of Moore graphs besides the sequence of cycle graphs $C_{2d+1}$?

(By definition a Moore graph must contain a cycle of length $2d+1$ where $d$ is its diameter, so complete graphs are ruled out by this reason.)

Comment: Complete graphs **are** Moore graphs: the shortest cycle in $K_n$ for $n\ge3$ has length $3=2d+1$, since $d=1$. [This] seems to indicate that no other infinite families are known.

Comment: @Brian, if that was supposed to link somewhere, please try again.

Comment: @Gerry: [Here’s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph#Examples) the missing link. (No idea what happened; thanks for catching it.)

Answer (score 3):

The set 
$$\text{{Moore graphs}} \setminus\left(\text{{odd cycles}}\cup \text{{complete graphs}}\right)$$
is finite. It consists of the trivial graph with one vertex, the Petersen graph, the Hoﬀman–Singleton graph, and some finite (possibly zero) number of graphs with diameter $2$ and degree $57$. See, e.g., [The Hoﬀman–Singleton graph and outer
automorphisms](http://users.minet.uni-jena.de/~matveev/Lehre/Graphentheorie/mj-hs.pdf) by Markus Junker or [Moore graphs and beyond: A survey of the degree/diameter problem](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS14).